# Trouble when connecting paired bluetooth headphones on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones, bluetooth-speaker

Couldn't find a working solution, please help. The bluetooth headphones can be paired, but not connected.

```
$ bluetoothctl

# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller F0:85:C1:FF:BD:A8 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 BT-1100
# scan off
Discovery stopped
[CHG] Controller F0:85:C1:FF:BD:A8 Discovering: no
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 RSSI is nil
# devices
Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 BT-1100
# pair FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01
Attempting to pair with FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 Connected: no
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 Connected: no
# connect FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01
Attempting to connect to FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 Connected: no
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device FC:58:FA:CF:D0:01 Connected: no
```

Logs:

```
Jan 05 00:59:00 host1 bluetoothd[536]: Unable to get connect data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Jan 05 00:59:02 host1 bluetoothd[536]: connect error: Connection reset by peer (104)
Jan 05 00:59:37 host1 bluetoothd[536]: connect error: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

Pulseaudio configs:

```
$ grep -P '(bluetooth|bluez)' /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/system.pa
/etc/pulse/default.pa:#.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
/etc/pulse/default.pa:load-module module-bluetooth-policy
/etc/pulse/default.pa:#.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
/etc/pulse/default.pa:load-module module-bluetooth-discover
/etc/pulse/system.pa:load-module module-bluez5-device
/etc/pulse/system.pa:load-module module-bluez5-discover
```

Packages installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -P '(bluetooth|bluez)'
ii  blueman                              2.1.2-1ubuntu0.2                           amd64        Graphical bluetooth manager
ii  bluez                                5.53-0ubuntu3                              amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-obexd                          5.53-0ubuntu3                              amd64        bluez obex daemon
ii  bluez-tools                          2.0~20170911.0.7cb788c-2build1             amd64        Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                  5.53-0ubuntu3                              amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth          1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8                       amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

$ uname -a
Linux host1 5.4.0-59-generic #65-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 10 12:01:51 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please help.

Comment: Please edit question and include the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: I tried suggestions from different web search results, but what ended up working for me was: I found and killed redundant pulseaudio processes.

Original posting as follows:

I also had trouble with pulseaudio failing to connect to my bluetooth headset sometimes, even after I had done the following:

- kill pulseaudio with:

```bash
pulseaudio -k
```

- unload module-bluetooth-discover with:

```bash
pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

- deleting pulseaudio config with:

```bash
rm -rf ~/.config/pulse
```

(Actually, I use a script to rename the directory to something else.)

- wait 6 seconds (in my script)
- restart the bluetooth service with:

```bash
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

- load module-bluetooth-discover once again with:

```bash
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

- restart pulseaudio with:

```bash
pulseaudio
```

(actually, it automatically restarts, but I thought I'd restart it just in case)

Sometimes the above would fix things, but sometimes pulseaudio refused to connect to the bluetooth headset, even though the bluetooth connection itself was obviously there, listed under blueman-manager (and also the headset made beeps to indicate that it was connected).

This is what I discovered tonight: it failed because there were multiple copies of pulseaudio running.  I found this with:

```bash
ps -ef | grep puls
```

I killed the older process with

```bash
kill 7734
```

(or whatever process number your output of the preceding command `ps -ef|grep pulse` showed)

Hopefully this covers all those cases where it previously did not connect.

Incidentally, sometimes there is an extra copy of `blueman-manager` running (ie. there is already one running before I run the "blueman-manager" command), and I have to use the "kill" command on it also, with `killall blueman-manager`.

Not sure if this helps you, but I wanted my answer to exist somewhere out there in searchable web space, because I kept finding a dozen or so responses to "pulseaudio doesn't connect to my bluetooth" but none of them solved my problem.